# CakePHP 2.0 add html table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, html-table

I'm trying to add rows to html tables in a CakePHP view and increment the id's/names where necessary. The code used to generate the table is:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('OrderDetail.0.product_code'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('OrderDetail.0.product_name'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('OrderDetail.0.product_qty'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('OrderDetail.0.product_price'); ?></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

CakePHP outputs the following html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="input text"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_code]" maxlength="100" type="text"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input text"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_name]" maxlength="255" type="text"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_qty]" step="any" type="number"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_price]" step="any" maxlength="24" type="number"/></div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

On clicking a link/button I would like a row added to the table in the same format but with the array incremented by 1 as such:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="input text"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_code]" maxlength="100" type="text"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input text"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_name]" maxlength="255" type="text"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_qty]" step="any" type="number"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[OrderDetail][0][product_price]" step="any" maxlength="24" type="number"/></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="input text"><input name="data[OrderDetail][1][product_code]" maxlength="100" type="text"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input text"><input name="data[OrderDetail][1][product_name]" maxlength="255" type="text"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[OrderDetail][1][product_qty]" step="any" type="number"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[OrderDetail][1][product_price]" step="any" maxlength="24" type="number"/></div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I can get the desired result using plain old Javascript, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. I have jQuery and the JSHelper loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution would be this

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    $("tr:last-child").clone().appendTo('tbody'); //clone the last row
    $("tr:last-child input").each(function() { //for each input in the last row, do the following
        var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name'); //get the whole value of attribute 'name'
        var newIndex = parseInt(nameAttr.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''))+1; //get the digit and add one
        $(this).attr('name',nameAttr.replace(/\d/,newIndex)); //replace the old digit with new

    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKxLh/

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked great. I had to modify $(":button"), $("tr:last-child"), and $("tr:last-child input") to make them refer to a specific element id (my page is more complicated than the example provided).

Answer (score 0):

Check this jQuery code:

```
$('#add_element').click(function(){
    var next_id = $('table tr').length;
    var clone_tr = $('table tr:first').clone();
    clone_tr.find('input').val('');

    clone_tr.find('input:eq(0)').attr('name', 'data[OrderDetail][' + next_id + '][product_code]');
    clone_tr.find('input:eq(1)').attr('name', 'data[OrderDetail][' + next_id + '][product_name]');
    clone_tr.find('input:eq(2)').attr('name', 'data[OrderDetail][' + next_id + '][product_qty]');
    clone_tr.find('input:eq(3)').attr('name', 'data[OrderDetail][' + next_id + '][product_price]');

    $('table tbody').append(clone_tr);

    return false;
});
```

I think you will need do this for id attribute too.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdRQW/). I hope it helps.